# Need help optimizing sumproduct in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sumproduct

I have the following code and i have not found a way to optimize it.
Any suggestions?

```
Range("K3").Value = [Sumproduct(((B:B)="Abierto")*((A:A)>=(G3))*((A:A)<=(eomonth(G3,0))))]
Range("K4").Value = [Sumproduct(((B:B)="Abierto")*((A:A)>=(G4))*((A:A)<=(eomonth(G4,0))))]
Range("K5").Value = [Sumproduct(((B:B)="Abierto")*((A:A)>=(G5))*((A:A)<=(eomonth(G5,0))))]
Range("K6").Value = [Sumproduct(((B:B)="Abierto")*((A:A)>=(G6))*((A:A)<=(eomonth(G6,0))))]
Range("K7").Value = [Sumproduct(((B:B)="Abierto")*((A:A)>=(G7))*((A:A)<=(eomonth(G7,0))))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rng as Range

set rng = Range("K3:K7")
rng.formula= "=Sumproduct(((B:B)=""Abierto"")*((A:A)>=(G3))*((A:A)<=(eomonth(G3,0))))"
```

The code will run faster if you choose the appropriate range instead of the entire column such as B:B, A:A.